# Directions request failed: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: google-maps-api-3

My Google Maps v3 Javascript application makes 7 or 8 calls to render driving directions to show multiple routes on a single web page.  I often get the above message; however, the directions are rendered.  In no instance do I exceed 2,500 calls a day.

My application is for a civic volunteer organization. I am in testing mode just now, but I do not want my users to see this message.  What should I do: 1) trap the message and wait for a time interval to resubmit my requests, 2) thinking that asking for the rendering in rapid succession is the problem, wait for a time interval between calls, 3) just ignore the limit message, because the rendering seems to go OK, or 4) contact Google to be more forgiving, because of the nature of my application?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the google maps API, but it would be helpful to indicate what specific API calls are giving you this error.

Comment: You exceeded number of calls per seconds. Check google docs and some other SO similar questions.